# identification-request prompt rework

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, identification-questions

Our current prompt for when you ask a question with the tag [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) is this:

[image]

Seeing as we don't allow image-only id-requests (see [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2473/1530)), maybe we should make it more clear that they need additional details.

If I was a new user and saw this - **it doesn't seem to indicate that asking an image-only question is inappropriate**, just that it should be reverse-searched beforehand.

I want to open the floor to the possibility of change to this feature.

Would it be good to change to something like:

> Are you trying to identify a series?
>
> Try and post as much information as possible - [See here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2473/1530) for question requirements

Although this removes the reverse search part of the prompt which isn't great either.

Opinions? Should we change it/leave it? Do you have your own better wording?

Comment: If possible, I think we should combine the current one with your proposal--have a popup that says something like "Trying to id a series? See here for question requirements. Trying to id the subject of an image? Try using Reverse image search first!" Or we could just ban id requests.

Comment: Well, that last bit is a whole other conversation - but perhaps, the only thing I was worried about was it possibly being quite long

Comment: Yeah, that last bit was a pseudo-not-very-funny joke that's sort of serious, which can be ignored for now. I agree it might get a bit long if we include all the necessary caveats. And in the end, any prompt is only useful if people read it. The benefit of your proposed change is that people who do care to read about how to improve their question get a complete reference on how to write a better question, instead of just disconnected advice.

Comment: I also think our new policies on image-only id requests have drastically reduced the problem they pose, so it makes sense to rework the prompt to address the problem of bad id requests more globally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was implemented, with just a slight change in the first paragraph of [ʞɹɐzǝɹ's suggestion](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2504/identification-request-prompt-rework/2520#2520), to reduce the amount of text in that little box:

[image: Current implementation]

The colour suggestions in ʞɹɐzǝɹ's answer have also been implemented, as can be seen above. Here's what the HTML looks like:

```
<span style="color:#F4F5F7">Please read our <b><a href="https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/891/what-criteria-should-we-use-for-qcing-for-all-identification-request-questions/892#892"  style="color:#FFF800">guidelines for identification request questions</a></b> to make sure you've included sufficient detail.
<br><br> If you're looking to identify an image, try doing a <b><a href="http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/how-can-i-identify-the-source-of-an-image-using-reverse-image-search" style="color:#FFF800">reverse image search</a></b> before asking.</span>
```

Comment: Good call on the text reduction. Thanks :)

Answer (score 12):

If anything in addition to a wording change, I'd like to suggest some accessibility enhancements to the dialog for better contrast within the existing stylesheet:

[image: Suggested tooltip]

<sub>**Link color:** #FFF800; **dialog button color**: #F4F5F7</sub>

> Before submitting your question please take some time to read over **[our guidelines](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/891/what-criteria-should-we-use-for-qcing-for-all-identification-request-questions/892#892)** for *"identification-request"* questions to make sure you've included sufficient detail.
>  If you're looking to identify an image, try doing a [**reverse image search**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/how-can-i-identify-the-source-of-an-image-using-reverse-image-search) before asking.

Comment: +1. The contrasting link color makes it more attention-attracting and indicates that the links are important.

Comment: Question - should we even bother with the reverse image search part as we could put  it in an easy-to-read place with the guidelines text

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko Better to be redundant. Link to the guidelines is an overview. The part about reverse image searching is intended more to be a reminder. (E.g. did you remember the lock the door? vs. This is how you lock the door.)

Comment: Also make sure this appear immediately after choosing id-req tag. Old version appear only after user leaving tag text box (when user press save button after choosing id-req this notification will only showing a few second before the page directed to question)

Answer (score 4):

I vote in favor of changing the current message.

As [We need to do something about the new users behind identification-request questions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2472/we-need-to-do-something-about-the-new-users-behind-identification-request-questi/2473#2473) Also covers the image part in it self.

> If the question have less than three (two for questions that include image(s), audio, and/or video(s)) of the the above mentioned criteria, or if the description provided is deemed to be too ambiguous, it will be put on hold as "Off-Topic: This identification request contains too little detail to be answered." You should edit your question to add more details, before it can be reopened.

I also think that link to [What criteria should we use for QCing for ALL "identification-request" questions?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/891/what-criteria-should-we-use-for-qcing-for-all-identification-request-questions/892#892) instead of the current one, as this is allot shorter. And I am pretty sure that most people are not waiting to read a huge wall of text, especially if they are not even taking the time to provide allot of details in their original question.

Comment: +1 overall, but it seems like image-based requests are a problem in themselves that needs (or needed) a separate solution. Almost none of the posts I've seen that have an image or video are actually saying "Hey, I watched this anime and I have this picture of it, the plot was blah blah...What was the title?" They're usually "Hey, I have this random picture from somewhere, what anime is it from?"

Comment: That's why I think it's still useful to have specific and prominent guidelines for image-based questions, instead of relying on the guidelines that seem to assume images are only used as supporting evidence. There's a gap between the case the guidelines were written for and what actually goes on, which I think new users need to be made aware of.

Comment: @Torisuda Maybe there should indeed come some sort of guidelines for *image only questions* such as providing at least the source where the find it. And a *minimum requirement* of the image such as quality etc. But if were to go in such details then I think going for a Media-identification-request tag would help us out allot. As this could cover audio/video/image identification requests, instead of the generalization of all such.

Answer (score 4):

What about something like this?

[image]

This points to the genral guidelines, but also suggests using reverse image search before posting image-only id-reqs.