# Change the identification request prompt

Tags: discussion, identification-questions

The current [prompt](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2504/2604) given when identification requests are asked is:

> Please read our [guidelines for identification request questions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/892/2604) to make sure you've included sufficient detail.
>
> If you're looking to identify an image, try doing a [reverse image search](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/how-can-i-identify-the-source-of-an-image-using-reverse-image-search) before asking.

Now that we've banned solely image-based identification requests, should we revise this prompt? In particular, a casual user might take this to imply that image identification is acceptable, particularly if she doesn't carefully read the guidelines in the link. (The specific answer linked doesn't make mention of the ban of image-only identification; it's a different answer to that question that does so.)

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko: yep, I was thinking of something like that.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer so

Answer (score 4):

What about:

> Please read [our guidelines for identification request questions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/892/2604) to make sure the type of question you are about to ask is on-topic and that you have included sufficient detail.

?

Comment: imo, "on-topic" is very weird for the new user since they asking about anime in anime QA site. Maybe "meet criteria" will be nice.

Comment: @SeptianPrimadewa: hmmm, as someone who has generally lurked on SE sites before joining it could make sense to me, but I'll admit that it might not do anything for someone who doesn't do that. Perhaps something like "make sure the type of question you are about to ask is acceptable for our site"?